# Proper verb form with Female Plural noun, Elles, and verb chanter, in present tense

Tags: usage

I am having a shirt made for an upcoming concert featuring L'Impératrice.
The wording on the shirt refers to Flore, the lead singer, and Angèle, another singer in another genre.  The wording says: They sing for the world.

I wrote it, "Elles chantent pour le monde."  But a friend said, in that
sentence you would not use 'chantent' but only 'chante'.   I want to use
the correct verb, including the verb a native speaker would use (rather than
a teacher in a French class!) HELP! Thank you very much.

Comment: Patrick, if there are two women, yours is right. Elles chantent pour le monde. Your friend either did not understand there were two women or doesn't even know how to conjugate the third person plural present tense of chanter in French.

Comment: You & Lambie are right. Sometimes French speakers find it hard to remember silent -ent endings in writing, but they're there. And if your friend is a learner then it's a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since the shirt refers to two females singers, the plural is indeed right:

> **Elles chantent** (pour le monde).

Answer (score -1):

Bonjour.

On peut utiliser le singulier ou le pluriel.

Si le verbe est au singulier, cela signifie que la personne qui porte le t-shirt chante pour le monde (une personne de sexe féminin).
Si le verbe est au pluriel, cela signifie que toutes les personnes qui portent le t-shirt chantent pour le monde (personnes de sexe féminin).
A vous de choisir

S’il y a à la fois des hommes et des femmes qui portent le t-shirt et qui chantent vous pourriez écrire :

- je change pour le monde
- nous chantons pour le monde

Comment: Il faut relire la question — on sait déjà qu'il s'agit de deux femmes qui chantent.

Comment: Dans ce cas il faut laisser le verbe au pluriel.

Comment: Mais si les tshirts sont portés uniquement par Flore et Angèle, alors on peut mettre le verbe au singulier.

Comment: Correction: En quoi le fait de **porter** le t-shirt change quoi que ce soit? C'est un slogan....

Comment: @Fréfré Oui, mais dans ce cas elles ne portent pas les t-shirts, les t-shirts font la promotion de leur musique et de leur message.

Comment: @Luke ***On chante le monde*** pourrait mettre tout le monde d'accord...

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, cela conviendrait.

Comment: *On chante pour le monde* even.